# Connecting Java with SQL express

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I've designed a database management system using Java and MySQL. I used **WAMP** as the server. Everything was perfect with that..until now..

Now, I have to go for **SQL Express** instead of **WAMP**. I know nothing about SQL Express. I've installed it under defaults.

However, now I can connect to the database in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** with following selections,
(`LORDXAX-PC` is my computer's name)

[image]

But I need to connect the database with my Java program. *(I've used **JDBC** successfully before, with WAMP)*

Need help to make this a success?? I've tried searching found certain things, but it gives errors. Can someone provide me with *clean* instructions..

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

### EDIT (2)

This is a complete code demonstrating the issue..

```
package ExpressTest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class MAIN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MAIN().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        System.out.println("START");
        String query = "SELECT * FROM logindata";
        getData(query);
        System.out.println("END");
    }

    public ResultSet getData(String query) {
        Connection CON = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            CON = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            RESULT = CON.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return RESULT;
    }
    private String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/brandix;instance=sqlexpress";
    private String USER = "";
    private String PASS = "";
    private static ResultSet RESULT;
}
```

This is the complete `NetBeans` output.

```
run:
START
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:417)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:185)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at ExpressTest.MAIN.getData(MAIN.java:24)
    at ExpressTest.MAIN.start(MAIN.java:16)
    at ExpressTest.MAIN.main(MAIN.java:10)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
END
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:311)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:261)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:318)
    ... 7 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: It is a good idea to create an application user in SQL express and use that in your JDBC URL instead of using domain account credentials. BTW, you could post the code snippet you are using to establish a connection for further help from the community.

Comment: "I've tried searching found certain things, but it gives errors.". What errors ? can you Provide code/ efforts ?

Comment: Enable mixed mode. http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-vps/mixedmode

Comment: @Vikdor Then all clients/users will use the same username and password combination and all with the same privileges?

Comment: Oh! I thought authorization controls at the SQL server layer are disconnected from the domain credentials. If they are connected, probably your approach is the apt one.

Comment: `good idea to create an application user` I have misunderstood this as a user for the whole application :)

Comment: @Vikdor I've edited the post to include the code as you asked. Also followed some of following answers, no success.. any help?

Comment: @HardikMishra please check the edited post. The exception i get is `Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect`..

Comment: @Anubis: Check is database service running ?. Try disabling firewall. If it works then add exception to Port No. 1433

Comment: @HardikMishra yes, databse is running (I can log in with `SQL Server Management Studio`). I tried dissabling both windows firewall and `Microsoft Security Essentials`. Still get the same exception..BTW, in the connection URL, i haven't included any port no (see my post). (Actually I followed MicSims answer.). Is that correct??

Comment: @HardikMishra I tried this `URL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/<MyDBname>;instance=sqlexpress"` and this `URL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<MyPCname>/<MyDBname>;instance=sqlexpress"`.. Still the same happens.. I don't prefer `JTDS` i used it as MicSim suggested (and i've heard it's better). But i can go for another connector, if that's the issue..

Comment: @Anubis: Can you provide full error stack trace ? Rather than one line exception.

Comment: @HardikMishra please see my post. I've included all the details. thanks for trying to help..

Comment: @Anubis: I have added an answer.It should solve your problem. Give it a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though many answers are available. I would like to give one.

As you are using Window Authentication.

Change JTDS URL from

```
private String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/brandix;instance=sqlexpress";
```

TO

```
private String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/brandix;instance=sqlexpress;useNTLMv2=tru‌​e;domain=workgroup";
```

OR Another alternative is:

Download the [Microsoft JDBC driver][1]rather than JTDS.
Add `sqljdbc4.jar` to your classpath.

Update your connection string (JDBC URL) for you server

Use `Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver);`

URL : `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=root;password=‌​123;"`

If still problem, persist. Check with,

Enable TCP/IP network protocol, which is disable by default, and set the TCP/IP port to 1433 which is again default port no.

1. Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager
   Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Then at the left hand tree. Select SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration-> Protocol for SQLEXPRESS-> TCP/IP.
3. Right click and enable it.
4. A window box appear on double click the TCP/IP. Click on the "IP Addresses" Tab
5. Set the TCP Port value to 1433 then click apply
6. Restart SQL Service.

Comment: Thanks, i've done as you said. How should i replace `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");` statement?

Comment: Ah, i've followed your previous answer..anyway, i'll try this too

Comment: I've done according to your edited answer. It throws this now: `java.sql.SQLException: The USENTLMV2 connection property is invalid.`. Do you want the full stacktrace? It's too long to put here, i'll add it to my post, if needed..

Comment: @Anubis: Remove the property. I have not deep idea on SQL server with Windows Authentication. If You can resintall to use it SQL server.

Comment: OK, i can login under `SQL Server Authentication` too. I've just now created a user `root` with password `123` and successfully connected to the database in `MS SQL Server Management Studio`. So, I thinks the problem is with the Java code. Let's get stick to `JTDS` or `MS JDBC`; anything you are prefer..what can i do now

Comment: Will you please provide me with a complete code using `Microsoft JDBC` you suggested..I'm stuck here. Tried everything I can..

Comment: Finally, i managed to make it run. You helped me a lot with this. Many thanks, really appreciate your help !!! I used `Ms JDBC`. I had to use `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` and `CON=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=root;password=123;");`.. Hope it'll help someone.. (I found that these differ from the ones you should use with `SQL server 2000`)

Comment: @HardikMishra Ohhh, so I didn't have the TCP/IP connections enabled. Visual Studio or LINQPad seem to not use the TCP/IP connection, because they were working fine. But I couldn't make it work in 0xDBE (from JetBrains). Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a driver capable to talk to SQL Server, like [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/index.html) for example.

Now for that case, your code would have to look similar to this:

```
public ResultSet getData(String query) {
    Connection CON = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        CON = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        RESULT = CON.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(">> " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return RESULT;
}
private String URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://servername/brandix;instance=sqlexpress";
private String USER = "";
private String PASS = "";
private static ResultSet RESULT;
```

Also see @SPee's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your instructions. Downloaded JTDS and added `jtds-1.2.6.JAR` to my project libraries (I'm using `Netbeans`). (But I haven't done anything else, like copying a dll or some other file to `\windows\*` directory...) Then I've tried using the above code. Well, at the first time, firewall appeared asking permission for access and I allowed it. Now every time I try to connect, it waits for couple of seconds and throws this exception,`Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect`. Any help?

Comment: See the FAQ for jTDS for this: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#connectionRefused. Also follow the instructions in this Microsoft article if needed: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277.

Answer (score 1):

[Basically your steps are](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+express+jdbc):

1. Install the [Microsoft JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774%20%22MS%20JDBC%20driver) of SQL Express into your classpath
2. Update your connection string (JDBC URL) for you server
3. Update your queries for SQL Express

Step 2 might require you to make SQL Express available through a TCP/IP connection, instead of a local pipe/named instance.

Step 3 might be the hardest. You must check your queries to be valid for SQL Express, use functions that exist with the correct parameters. And for a Database Management System you must also update all your queries for user management, table management, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First download the JDBC-Driver from the microsoft website.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Add `sqljdbc4.jar` to your application.

Copy the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` in `c:\windows\system32` and the `/bin` folder of your java installation.

You can use a connection url like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://D-PC-IT-02;instanceName=LOKALEINSTANZ;databaseName=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;
```

A reboot may be necessary.