# Connect JAVA with SQLEXPRESS

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm not experienced in using `SQL Express`. So I'll try to provide all the details I see important.
(It'll make the post a bit long. But there may be some unnecessary details, please go through)

I recently installed `Microsoft SQL Server 2008` (there are 2 items in start menu as `Microsoft SQL Server 2008` and `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`)

I need to communicate with a SQL Express database. Actually, I could do it successfully, with my locally installed Database ([This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12103261/1547699) of mine, helped me with it). But I need to use it in our office.

Same version of `SQL Express` is installed in those machines. But I can't use my JAVA program in those machines, it throws this kind of exception.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:241)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2243)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:491)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1309)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    at JDBC_TEST.TEST.getData(TEST.java:57)
    at JDBC_TEST.TEST$1.actionPerformed(TEST.java:44)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Though I tried the whole day to fix the issue, couldn't figure out a way. But there is some thing I found, think it has something to do with this.

This is a screenshot of my local machines `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

[image]

**The program works Under this conditions.** So It seems my program make use of the `MSSQLSERVER` service (only).

But in my office computer, though `SQL Express` version is the same (because, I used the same setup to install it in my computer) I found that, this **`MSSQLSERVER` service is not available** there. It shows only some of the above services. (`SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`, `SQL Server Browser` and some other service)

Unfortunately, I can't change the configurations of our office database. So I need to know whether I can change my program to communicate with the database through the available `SQLSERVER` service.

Following is a simple (complete) code, to demonstrate how I'm trying to do the communication. (I'm using [Microsoft JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774))

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TEST extends JFrame {

    JTextField stringField;
    JButton tryButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TEST().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        stringField = new JTextField("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=root;password=123;");
        tryButton = new JButton("TRY");
        getContentPane().add(stringField);
        getContentPane().add(tryButton);
        pack();
        tryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    ResultSet rSet = getData(stringField.getText());
                    rSet.first();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(tryButton, rSet.getString("username"), "DONE !", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    rSet.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static ResultSet getData(String URL) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection CON = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        String query = "SELECT * FROM logindata;";
        Statement st = CON.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet RESULT = st.executeQuery(query);
        return RESULT;
    }
}
```

I wrote this to try changing the connection strings..

Hope there will be some way to solve this. Any help is highly appreciated..
Thanks!

Comment: did you try replacing localhost with a FQDN of the machine? That is the best way so that the program can be run from anywhere.

Comment: Verify the port no that is used. Both the systems may have different port to support tcp/ip connection.

Comment: @sshekhar I checked, no issue with the port..

Comment: @Vikdor And what is that, not something familiar. If that's a sure solution, I'll go for it. Will you provide some example, a simple one. Thanks!

Comment: FQDN is fully-qualified-domain-name like abc.company.com instead of using localhost.

Comment: @Vikdor Well, the issue here is not that. Because, when `MSSQLSERVER` service is running, this code works without any prob. But when it's not there, this fails. So I need to know how to connect without `MSSQLSERVER` (but `SQLSERVER` service is running..)

Answer (score 7):

Steps

Open the Sql Server Configuration Manager (Start -> Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools)

Expand SQL Server Network Configuration -> [Your Server Instance]

Double click TCP/IP

Under Protocol:

Ensure Enabled is Yes

Under IP Addresses:

Scroll to the bottom and set the TCP Port under IPAll, (1433 by default)

Find the IP address you want to connect to and set Enabled and Active to Yes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the system is already implemented as given in **my** answer (using SQLExpress 2005). I've tried what you suggested. But it wasn't successful..

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error message contains the tip for you. Are you trying to connect to remote machine? Is personal firewall running on your or remote machine?

If answers to both questions are true, check the firewall configuration. I usually try to stop firewall and then, when everything is working add exception rule and start it again. You can refer to firewall events log to check what is going on.

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. I even tried with locally installed server (with same conditions). Yeah, I've tried adding exceptions, enabling mixed modes, turning off firewalls, changing ports, allowing dynamic port assignment etc,etc... Nothing worked..

Comment: answer by @AlexR is close, have to start SQLExpress, enable port 1433 on FW (blocked by default in Win7 / 2008) only non_free SQL Servers instalation enable that, [change syntax (must contains SQLEXPRESS)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5916561/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel I've already enabled the port. Will you tell me whether this `SQLSERVER` service can be used instead of `MSSQLSERVER`. That's the point (i think) that we have to focus on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Go to 
`Start > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`

When it opens Go to

```
 SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress
```

Where you'll find the Protocol TCP/IP, if disabled then Enable it Click on TCP/IP, You'll find its properties.

In this properties **Remove All the TCP Dynamic Ports and Add value of 1433 to all TCP Port**
and restart your `SQL Server Services > SQL Server`

And Its Done...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your database user password. Make sure new password doesn't have special characters. I faced same problem and it got resolved after changing the db password. Steps of my workaround:

I was getting sqlserverexception.java 190 error stating unable to connect to host port: 4500 which was my localhost port. Opened Sql Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> Enabled TCP/IP. Checked TCP port number. It was 1433. So I changed 4500 to 1433 in my registry file.

After following above steps, I got a different error this time stating password for my db user(sql-test) is incorrect. I changed the password to sqltest123 and it worked.